# Add jar file to spring-boot classpath at runtime

Tags: plugins, classpath, spring-boot

I want develop a modular application using **spring-boot** and **plugins**. The plugins will be handled with **spring-plugin** and these are stored in jars files in a directory (for example: /home/application/plugins).How can I add jars files to the application classpath at runtime and loading classes and beans (plugins) that are in these jars files.
Best regards, HLicea

Answer (score 6):

You need to use PropertiesLauncher instead of JarLauncher:

```
java -cp "yourBoot.jar" -Dloader.path=plugins/ -Dloader.main=your.mainClass org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

This will make java load the jars in the plugins directory and spring load all the classes in those jars marked as @Configuration into the context.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "standard" java approach should work here, e.g. for Linux:

```
java -cp "yourBoot.jar:plugins/*" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Only trick is that I have taken `Main-Class` from boot's uberjar.

Comment: The spring-boot log show this trace: 2015-02-25 14:15:38.794  WARN 31143 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Skipping [/home/hlicea/Work/Java/samples/prueba-plugins-boot/target/plugins/plugin-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar] **because it does not denote a directory**

Comment: is it causing problems and what kind? because I just tried simple `Class.forName()` to verify proper classpath and it was working (and I can see same warning as you).

Comment: But Spring don't create beans store in jars files (plugins)

Comment: it throws exception:
`Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

Comment: classname might have change since spring boot v1.