# Move spring boot lib folder outside of jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing **spring-boot** application. After building the project, the size of jar file becomes 40 MB which 99% of it is dependencies that exits in BOOT-INF\lib.
I'd like to **move the lib folder outside of generated jar file** and upload it only once to server and upload just the project jar file since then in order to rapid deployment.
How is it possible to do that?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: outline:1.  make sure the libs are available in your server. 2.  you can (in maven) set the dependency scope to `provided` (gradle: `providedCompile`/`..Runtime`), this will exclude them from the resulting jar. (3. check, whether spring-plugin "did no tricks"...i.e. added/re-packaged them somehow)

Comment: for details on 3.: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#repackage

Comment: And you can load the libraries using `-Dloader.path` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28725846/10871900).

Comment: ..yes, i think step 2. will not exclude them from the boot-jar/war! (but maybe still useful) For an answer I would cite [all of this (chapter 5)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#repackage)

Comment: Basically you need to reconfigure your build to generate a jar not a fat-jar, which is all bathe previous comments are getting at.

Comment: @xerx593 I changed the scope of spring-boot-starter to provided but the lib folder is still there.

Comment: I could do it by cut the `lib` folder and paste it outside of jar and running command below. But this way is weird.                                                                               
`java -cp "yourBoot.jar" -Dloader.path=plugins/ -Dloader.main=your.mainClass org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`